# Analog Clock, Rotate Hands C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF project, trying to create an analog clock. I have an image of a clock (without the hands) and have set it as a background. I also have images of two hands of clock, which I want to rotate keeping one end fixed (like it happens in a clock). How can I rotate the image keeping its one end fixed in C#.NET (WPF)? What I have tried is the following code:

```
namespace AnalogWatch
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    private int degrees = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        degrees += 5;
        if (degrees > 360)
        {
            degrees = 0;
        }
        RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(degrees,StickImg.Width/2,StickImg.Height/2);
        //StickImg.RenderTransformOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0);
        StickImg.RenderTransform = transform;
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

}

It is rotating the image but not keeping its one end fixed. What is the problem here ?

XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="AnalogWatch.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered_1">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="StickImg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="207,70,0,0" Source="stick.png"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you describe the motion of the end that is supposed to be fixed? Are you sure that the center of rotation of the image coincides with the end of the clock hand?

Comment: What happened to your other question that was just like this one? Did you delete it? If you did, its probably OK, but to try and avoid a question ban, its better to edit than delete (though you may have a hard time recovering from the downvotes).

Comment: Also, it looks like your center is wrong. You probably want the center to be *at* Width/Height, not at the midpoint.

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly is right without a more complete code example (where's the XAML?), but as Bradley says, you need to set the centerpoint of the rotation to the correct location. What the "correct location" is depends on how you're defining the clock hand in the first place. Note also that the rotation origin is a convenience; you can also translate your object so that the center of rotation is at (0,0), do the rotation, and then translate it so that the center of rotation is in the center of the clock (i.e. combine a translate, a rotate, and then another translate).

Comment: Added XAML to question.

Comment: Added working picture to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated.**

**Your code should work if clock hand exactly in the center of rectangular image.**
Like this one
[image]

You can do either like you did

```
RotateTransform transform =new RotateTransform(degrees, StickImg.Width/2,StickImg.Height/2);
```

or

```
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(degrees);
StickImg.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) of the element to set the center of rotation.

Note that the coordinates are scaled to 0..1
So to rotate around the center:

```
RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
```

Just make sure that the pivot of the hand is in the center of the element.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code i'm using and it works like charm..as **qwr** suggested clock hand should be exactly in the center of rectangular image

c# code

```
    DispatcherTimer clock = new DispatcherTimer();
    public AnalogClock()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        clock.Interval =TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        clock.Tick += clock_Tick;
        clock.Start();
    }

    void clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double milsec = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        double sec = DateTime.Now.Second;
        double min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        double hr = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        seconds.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(((sec / 60) * 360)+((milsec/1000)*6));
        minutes.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform((min * 360 / 60)+((sec/60)*6));
        hours.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform((hr * 360 / 12)+(min/2));

    }
```

and the XAML code for images

```
<Grid Margin="-100">
    <Image x:Name="clockface" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="images/panel.PNG" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="194" Margin="100" Width="194"/>
    <Image x:Name="hours" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="images/hours.PNG" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="194" Margin="100" Width="194"/>
    <Image x:Name="minutes" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="images/minutes.PNG" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="194" Margin="100" Width="194"/>
    <Image x:Name="seconds" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="images/seconds.PNG" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="194" Margin="100" Width="194"/>
</Grid>
```

note the i've used the code in a separate usercontrol..

just make sure that the margin between the clock hand image and the grid i'ts contained in should be enough to make room for the image to rotate else it will displace while rotating..

hope this helps..!